# $\sup\{t_{1}f_{n}(x_{1})+t_{2}f_{n}(x_{2})\mid n\geq n_{0}\}=\sup\{t_{1}f_{n}(x_{1})\mid n\geq n_{0}\}+\sup\{t_{2}f_{n}(x_{2})\mid n\geq n_{0}\} $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

I was thinking, if this is correct:

Let $f_n$ is a series of convex, limited function $I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \ \ \ t_1 + t_2 = 1$

Is that a true statement :

$\sup\{t_{1}f_{n}(x_{1})+t_{2}f_{n}(x_{2})\mid n\geq n_{0}\}=\sup\{t_{1}f_{n}(x_{1})\mid n\geq n_{0}\}+\sup\{t_{2}f_{n}(x_{2})\mid n\geq n_{0}\}$?

.Edit

$f_n$ are all convex and have a finite upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

The "$\leq$" direction is true under more general circumstances. The "$\geq$" does not hold generally, and does not appear to have to do with convexity.

For the sake of argument, fix $t_1 = t_2 = 1/2$ and $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 1$. Let $f_1, f_2$ be parabolae for which $f_1(0) = -1, f_1(1) = 1$ and $f_2(0) = 1, f_2(1) = -1$. Set $f_{2k} = f_2, f_{2k+1} = f_1$.

We can see that $t_1 f_n(0) + t_2 f_n(1) =0$ for any $n$, so that the left-hand quantity is equal to 0. On the right-hand side, $t_1 f_n(0)$ attains its supremum at $1/2$ and $t_2 f_n(1)$ at $1/2$, so the right hand side equals to 1.

The only way to ensure the $\geq$ direction is to know something about the sequence of functions $f_n$ as they relate to each other; for instance, the sequence might be increasing to a finite limit, or equicontinuous or whatnot. As it stands though you need more hypotheses to say something.

Comment: Oh sorry, they are all convex and have a finite upper limit. Could You say something more now?

Comment: @Steve What do you mean by finite upper limit? Do you mean that the $f_n$'s are defined on a bounded interval $I$ and are bounded on that interval? It likely doesn't matter, though, because this conclusion has nothing to do with being convex.