# Define $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x)= \sup {f_n(x) : n \geq n_0 }$ for $ x \in I$, It's convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose, that $f_n:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are convex functions for $n\geq n_0$ and

$\forall_{x\in I} \exists_{y\in \mathbb{R}} \forall_{n\geq n_0} f_n(x)\leq y$

Define $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x)= \sup \{f_n(x) \mid n \geq n_0 \}$ for $ x \in I$

Please help me prove, that $f$ is convex .

What I've tried - write fromulas from definition, try to glue then, but nothing work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your definition of $f$. Where does $n_0$ spring from, for example?

Comment: Only $n_0$ should be replaced by $1$, say.

Comment: @copper.hat I've used tex not correctly, not should be clear

Comment: Is $n_0$ a fixed number?

Comment: Yes, it's a fixed number

Answer (score 2):

Try using the characterisation of convexity which goes like this: $f$ is convex on $I$ exactly when
$$f(tx + (1-t)y) \le tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$$ 
for any $x, y \in I$ and $t \in [0,1]$, assuming $I$ is convex. Also remember that for bounded sets $A, B \ne \{ \}$ we have
$$\sup (A+B) = \sup A + \sup B,$$
where $A + B = \{ a + b : a \in A, b \in B \}.$

Comment: Sorry, but the last statement is not true.

Comment: About the supremum of $A+B$? It is true, assuming $A, B$ are (bounded) non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Even if they're not bounded above you can state it.

Comment: Counter example is here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350505/sup-t-1f-nx-1t-2f-nx-2-mid-n-geq-n-0-sup-t-1f-nx?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I haven't looked in detail at the question, but it doesn't look resolved. The fact I'm stating here is very easy to prove; try it yourself.

Comment: It must be true that $\sup (A+B) = \sup A + \sup B$. Remember that you are adding sets, so all possible combinations get added.

Answer (score 2):

If $\{f_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a collection of convex functions, then $\sup_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha$ (defined pointwise) is convex.

One way to see this is to notice that $\operatorname {epi} \sup_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha = \cap_{\alpha \in A} \operatorname {epi} f_\alpha$, and the intersection of an arbitrary collection of convex sets is convex.

A direct way is to notice that if $\lambda \in [0,1] $, then 
$$f_\alpha(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda f_\alpha(x) + (1-\lambda) f_\alpha(y), \ \ \ \forall \alpha$$
Hence we have
$$f_{\alpha'}(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda \sup_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x) + (1-\lambda) \sup_{\alpha \in A}  f_\alpha(y), \ \ \ \forall \alpha'$$
Now take the $\sup$ over $\alpha'$ to get 
$$\sup_{\alpha' \in A} f_{\alpha'}(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda \sup_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha(x) + (1-\lambda) \sup_{\alpha \in A}  f_\alpha(y)$$
Hence $\sup_{\alpha \in A} f_\alpha$ is convex.

In your case, $A = \{n | n \ge n_0 \}$.